# Is it possible to enable inner attributes project-wide?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'd like to enable a variety of attributes, such as lints and unstable features, like these:

```
#![feature(try_trait)]
#![deny(unused_must_use)]
```

Is this possible using Cargo or another method?

**Update**: The first comment answers the question

Comment: Using an inner attribute at the top of your project root (`mod.rs` or `main.rs`) does exactly that.